# How to use the Service Account credentials for SecretManagerServiceClient without using a json file

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, credentials, service-accounts, google-secret-manager

I am using the below code for accessing the service account credentials, Not sure Since the secret manager does not accept a credential in their Create(), So I tried the second approach as per https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code.
What Am I doing wrong?

```
        var text = File.ReadAllText(@"cred.json");
        JObject credential = JObject.Parse(text);

        SecretManagerServiceClientBuilder secretManagerServiceClientBuilder = new SecretManagerServiceClientBuilder()
        {
            JsonCredentials = o1,
        };
        SecretManagerServiceClient client = secretManagerServiceClientBuilder.Build();
        // Create the client.
        client = SecretManagerServiceClient.Create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution -

Accessing the service account via code can be done in 2 ways -

1. Check if the API accepts the credentials in the create method like for the storage bucket, then use the first approach.

   ```
       var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath);
       var storage = StorageClient.Create(credential);
   ```
2. If create() do not accept params then user the builder for that API Like SecretManagerServiceClientBuilder for the secret manager, KeyManagementServiceClientBuilder for KMS. Just replace the create part with the builder part.

   ```
   var text = File.ReadAllText(@"cred.json");
   SecretManagerServiceClientBuilder secretManagerServiceClientBuilder = new SecretManagerServiceClientBuilder()
   {
       JsonCredentials = text,
   };
   SecretManagerServiceClient client = secretManagerServiceClientBuilder.Build();
         SecretVersionName secretVersionName = new SecretVersionName(projectId, secretId, secretVersionId);

       // Call the API.
       AccessSecretVersionResponse result = client.AccessSecretVersion(secretVersionName);

       // Convert the payload to a string. Payloads are bytes by default.
       String payload = result.Payload.Data.ToStringUtf8();
   ```

Comment: `JsonCredentials` is a string.