Generate a long-term access token for a service account to access Google API
I have a service account foo. For this service account I want to create an authorization token so I can run my program in a CI/CD pipeline and letting it communicate with the Google API.
I researched how to retrieve a long-term token by checking out this documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth
My problem here is that I have to do so many steps just for that token.

Create JWT header and claim
Generate signature for JWT
Use created JWT to actually retrieve Auth Token
Use Auth Token...

Why can't I use the JWT token in the first place to access the Google API? Why do I need to ask for another token? It feels a bit overengineered tbh.

What mean "long term" for you?

As mentioned in this blog:

OAuth: Open Authorization (OAuth) is an open standard for token-based authentication over public networks.OAuth allows
third-party services such as Facebook and Google to use end-user
account information without exposing the user’s account credentials to
a third party.
JWT: JSON Web Tokens (JWT) are an open industry standard for sharing information between two entities, typically a client (the
front end of an application) and a server (the back end of an
application).
JWT is a token that contains claims about the user or client. OAuth
uses a unique token to grant access to the user’s resources. OAuth
tokens are security tokens granted by IDP that can only be validated
by that same OAuth token provider. You can use JWT as another kind of
OAuth token.
JWT is better suited to APIs. OAuth is useful for web, API, and
browser applications and resources.

Lifetime of the access token can be extended. To do so, choose the service accounts that need an extended lifetime for access tokens, then add these service accounts to an organization policy that includes the constraints/iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension list constraint.
If you want to extend the token lifetime beyond the default, you must create an organization policy that enables the iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension constraint. You can't create access tokens with an extended lifetime for user credentials or external identities. Check this official GCP document for more information.
As per this official GCP document on Generate the access token :

If you use the REST API, and your system is configured to allow
extended token lifetimes, you can create a token with a lifetime
longer than the default. The Google Cloud CLI does not support setting
a lifetime for the token.

Now about “Why can't I use the JWT token in the first place to access the Google API? ”
The JWT token is only valid for a short period of time (typically one hour), and it cannot be used to access the Google API directly. It may seem an extra step and a bit over-engineered using a JWT token adds an extra layer of security and ensures only authorized users are accessing the google APIs, it provides a more secure way to access Google APIs and prevents misuse of API resources.
Why do I need to ask for another token?
Another or two-step process helps to improve security by ensuring that your JWT token is not compromised. If your JWT token is stolen, it can only be used to request an access token, which will expire after a short period of time. This helps to protect your Google API resources from unauthorized access.
Check Google Cloud Community forum discussion for more information.

It actually can depend on the Google API you need to call. I believe my situation is similar to yours, and I have been researching this for days. I can't believe how complicated Google has made it, but fortunately for my needs of calling the Google Cloud Secret Manager API over HTTP REST, I can use what they call "Self-signed JWT". You can find some technical documentation for that at:
https://google.aip.dev/auth/4111.
But it sounds like you have that part down.
The next piece of information I found was to the same link you listed:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth
It states:

With some Google APIs, you can make authorized API calls using a signed JWT directly as a bearer token, rather than an OAuth 2.0 access token. When this is possible, you can avoid having to make a network request to Google's authorization server before making an API call.

That is exactly what I want. And sounds like what you want too. So it might be helpful for you to mention what, exactly, Google API(s) you need to call. The documentation goes on to say:

If the API you want to call has a service definition published in the Google APIs GitHub repository, you can make authorized API calls using a JWT instead of an access token.

Now, I'm not exactly sure what they mean by "...has a service definition published...". But for example, there is a "folder" for the Google Cloud Secret Manager here. If that is what they mean by "...has a service definition published...", then hopefully that is a good sign, because there are many. Hopefully what you need is listed there.
Given that, I can then simply review that API's documentation and make a simple HTTP REST request containing my self-signed JWT. For example, to get the latest version of a secret, I can generate a new self-signed JWT, with an expiration time of one hour, then make an HTTP call to:
GET https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-company-project-name/secrets/my-secret-name/versions/latest:access
Authorization: Bearer ey0asdfasdf....

And I never have to go through any of the "multi-leg" OAuth steps, or worry about expiring tokens, or refresh tokens. That part is awesome. But why Google thinks it is any better or more secure than using an API Key is beyond me. At least with the API Key, Google allows you to not only put the obvious permissions limitations as to what the API Key can be used to access, but also do things like put IP address restrictions on it. You can't do that with self-signed JWTs. Unfortunately very few of the Google APIs allow using API Keys.
Here is a screen shot of my service account's private key listing. The private key (a small JSON file), that is created will be downloaded through your browser, and will never expire.

Once you have all of that, one last key (no pun intended) piece of information for me came from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66489363/8169136
which mentions, for many of the Google API client SDK libraries, in order to do something simple, like specify the location of the JSON private key file, as opposed to using their stupid "Application Default Credentials" (hello, I'm in a multi-user server environment), you can do so by using the *Builder class of the API's client library. So again, for me, with the Secret Manager API, I could then do:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/66489363/8169136
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\GoogleCloudSecretManager\application_default_credentials.json");
var secretManagerServiceClientBuilder = new SecretManagerServiceClientBuilder
{
    JsonCredentials = text,
};

var client = secretManagerServiceClientBuilder.Build();
var secretVersionName = new SecretVersionName(projectID, secretID, secretVersionID);

// Call the API.
var result = client.AccessSecretVersion(secretVersionName);

// Convert the payload to a string. Payloads are bytes by default.
var payload = result.Payload.Data.ToStringUtf8();

Log(payload);

I cannot believe it took multiple days of research to get a solid understanding of, and to be able to write those few lines of code.
Just in case, for reference, the service account's private key that gets downloaded, as a JSON file, should look something like:

Note, I just named the file as application_default_credentials.json in order to first get it working with the default sample code that relies on the file existing with that name in the %APPDATA%\gcloud\ directory (when on Windows).
P.S.
There is still one part that I would like to do, that I haven't figured out yet, but it sounds like you may have figured it out. You mention, what sounds like creating a self-signed JWT, and then using it to make a call to Google to get an OAuth token. What HTTP call would that be? I would like my application to do this, as a one time "test connection" operation. I've tried many things, but I cannot use my self-signed JWT on anything other than the single secret that I have granted my service account permissions to. Perhaps I need to grant my service account some other permission? For example, I tried sending the JWT to things like:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=eyJhbGci...

POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

But they all return some kind of error, a rather ambiguous error.
